# How to check if text contains specific characters before printing (xpath)?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, nodes

So right now I have this code, which works great:

This takes anything that's in the xpath and print.

```
<?php
$parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
$html_string = file_get_contents('http://www.weburladresshere.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$values = array();
$row = $xpath->query('myquery');
foreach($row as $value) {
   print($value->nodeValue);
}

?>
```

I need to insert two things into the code (if possible):

1. To check if the content is longer than x characters, then don't print.
2. To check if the content contains http in the content, then don't print.

If both of the above are negative - take it and print it.

If one of them is positive - skip, and then check the secondquery on the same page:

```
$row = $xpath->query('secondquery');
```

If this also contains one of the above, then check the thirdquery (from the same page) and so on.
Until it matches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For #1 above - Content as in the full HTML content or the `print($value->nodeValue);` content size?

Comment: That's a good question. I think either would work, as long as it is easier to implement and as long as it will display the desired result.

Comment: They will have two completely different answers though. The threshold you set for all characters found in the overall HTML will be very different than that of a single line. That's why I'm asking there

Comment: In a single line. So I guess the print($value->nodeValue); content size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from the question you want a way to continue to run queries on the `DOMDocument` and evaluate the following conditions.

1. If the string length of the `nodeValue` is below a threshold
2. If the string of `nodeValue` does not contain "http"

Logic conditions:

- IF both of those above are true then echo to the screen
- IF one of those are false then run the next subquery

Below is the code which uses 500 characters as the length. My example has 3 entries which have the following character counts: 294, 98, and 1305.

```php
<?php
/**
 * @param $xpath
 * @param $xPathQueries
 * @param int $iteration
 */
function doXpathQuery($xpath, $xPathQueries, $iteration = 0)
{
    // Validate there's no more subquery to go through
    if (!isset($xPathQueries[$iteration])) {
        return;
    }

    $runNextIteration = false;
    // Run the XPATH subquery
    $rows = $xpath->query($xPathQueries[$iteration]);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $value = trim($row->nodeValue);
        $smallerThanLength = (strlen($value) < 500);
        
        // Case insensitive search, might use "http://" for less false positives
        $noHttpFound = (stristr($value, 'http') === FALSE);

        // Is it smaller than length, and no http found?
        if($smallerThanLength && $noHttpFound) {
            echo $value;
        } else {
            // One of them isn't true so run the next query
            $runNextIteration = true;
        }
    }

    // Should we do the next query?
    if ($runNextIteration) {
        $iteration++;
        doXpathQuery($xpath, $xPathQueries, $iteration);
    }
}

// Commented out this next line because I'm not sure what it does in this context
// $parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );

// Get all the contents for the URL
$html_string = file_get_contents('https://theeasyapi.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// Container that will hold all the rows that match the criteria
$values = [];

// An array containing all of the XPATH queries you want to run
$xPathQueries = ['/html/body/div/section', '/html/body/div'];
doXpathQuery($xpath, $xPathQueries);
```

This will run all of the queries put in `$xPathQueries` as long as the query produces a value where the string length is above 500 or 'http' is found.

Comment: Perfect. Worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks for the effort in taking the time writing the code. Appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to hear it! Good luck on your project